Linux C-Shell - If statement on AWK piped from WC
I have the following code which is doing a wc -lc command piping it into an AWK command which prints the file size in MB and the row count inside its content.  It works good if the file "file.csv" exists, but if doesn't, the intent is to print 0 0 but it just do nothing but printing the error message "No such file or directory", here i have the code:
wc -lc < "file.csv" | awk '{if($1) {FileSize = $2 / 1024 / 1024; RecordCount = $1 - 1; print FileSize, RecordCount} else{FileSize = 0; RecordCount = 0; print FileSize, RecordCount}}'

Result:
file.csv: No such file or directory.

It doesn't print 0 0 which this is what i am expecting if the file is not found.

You have the rc-shell applied tag -- really?! That's an extremely unusual shell.

@CharlesDuffy The title says C-shell. Not quite as unusual.

@Barmar, ...indeed. Horrid idea to use it, but lots of people have bad ideas.

Do you want file.csv: No such file or directory. to be printed if the file doesn't exist or would you prefer that is not printed and you just get 0 0 out, same as you would for a file that exists but is empty?

You could fix the awk code to make it handle both cases:
wc -lc < file.csv |
awk 'END {print $2/1024/1024, ($1 ? $1-1 : 0)}'

The idea is to make use of the END block which is always executed by awk (even when the input stream is empty).
Inside the END block, the values of NR, $1, $2, etc... are the same as when processing the last record, so depending on the output of wc -lc, those variables could be defined or not, but it doesn't matter as you can make them be equal to 0 implicitly when doing an arithmetic operation with them (for eg. the result of "" + 0 is 0).

This has worked awesomely! thank you so much.  Could you explain each element on the AWK string?

Just the only thing, on the rc, if the file exists ... i need to subtract 1 always because the header ....

@MarcoSomoza I added a few explanations and a test for taking the header into account

You could always just let awk count the lines and characters:
awk 'BEGIN{ while ( (getline < ARGV[1]) > 0 ) { nr++; nc+=length() }; print nr+0, nc / 1024 / 1024; exit }' file.csv

That'll work whether file.csv exists or not. It wont print file.csv: No such file or directory. if the file doesn't exist, it'll just produce the same 0 0 output as it will for an empty file, idk if that's desirable or not.

Consider the following:
wc -lc < "file.csv" |
awk '
BEGIN { print "BEGIN" }
      { print "body"  }
END   { print "END"   }'

When file.csv does not exist this will generate:
bash: file.csv: No such file or directory
BEGIN
END

This shows us the awk script receives no data lines to process.
OP's current awk script is coded such that it will only generate output when it sees a line of input.
Modifying OP's script to address no lines of input by moving the print logic to an END block:
wc -lc < "file.csv" |
awk '
    { FileSize = $2 / 1024 / 1024
      RecordCount = $1 - 1
    }
END { print FileSize+0, RecordCount+0 }'

Where:

if the body of the script does not fire (eg, there are no lines of input to process) then when we get to the END block  ...
FileSize and RecordCount are undefined (will print as blank) so ...
by adding +0 to both variables we force awk to print 0's instead of blanks

